# import python functions into serversless

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I h got an issue with the following serverless config.

[image]

this is my handler and the files/folders structure.

[image]

[image]

the issue is that after uploading my project to AWS when I test my lambda I got an error as follows:

lambda execution fails: "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app_monitor': No module named 'monitoring'"

{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'src/app_monitor': No module named 'monitoring'",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"requestId": "bca3f67d-815f-452b-a2a6-c713ad2c6baa",
"stackTrace": []
}

have you got any clue how can I add this into serverless config.?

Answer (score 1):

First, a quick tip on troubleshooting: When I ran into such issues it was helpful to go to the AWS console, look at the lambda function, and see what the uploaded file structure looks like on that end. Is the monitoring folder there?

Moreover, in order to specify how a specific function is packaged, you have to explicitly state that you want it to be individually packaged and not follow the general rules of the project as a whole.

You should try to add:

```
app_monitoring:
 package:
   individually: true
   patterns:
     -  'src/**'
```

More documentation on packaging configuration [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging)

You may also have better luck with explicitly stating the patterns you need, I know I've had issues with globs in the past. So for example you can try:

```
patterns:
  - 'src/app_monitoring.py'
  - 'src/monitoring/get_lb.py'
```

Comment: Hello m.oulmakki  thanks you for your comments I have also found a very interesting article that helped me to workaround this issue -- https://medium.com/@nate_mitchell/serverless-packaging-user-defined-python-modules-41808776eae0 --- especially how to handle the requirelements.txt